# Cannot execute Praat commands on Linux command line

Tags: linux, command-line, praat

I am trying to test praat (5.3.16) on linux (ubuntu 14.04) command line by running the command below

```
/usr/bin/praat --open data/hello.wav data/hello.TextGrid
```

It opens the praat gui "Praat Object" and "Praat Picture" but they are both empty, the terminal does not have ">" indicating that praat is running but nothing is happening.

Please let me know how to execute praat on command line, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Praat's release notes](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/What_s_new_.html), the `--open` switch on the command line was only introduced in version 6.0 (and still got a bugfix for multiple files in version 6.0.22):

> 6.0 (28 October 2015)
>
> [...]
>   Praat can now open files from the command line on all platforms.
>   [...]

The version you mention is almost 7 years old (May 23, 2012), so if that's possible, you probably need to update to a more recent version to have all new features and bug fixes that were made since then.